# Connect to Azure SQL Server using User Assigned managed identity using SSMS fails

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, ssms, azure-managed-identity

I cannot connect to an Azure SQL DB using a user-assigned managed identity. The SQL is reachable from a SQL VM running SQL Server 2017 using private endpoints and is able to connect using service principals and an Entra ID account with MFA.

- The Entra ID auth-only button is checked, and the managed identity is part of the SQL admin group in Azure.
- The Identity has both contributor and SQL DB contributor for the server:

[Azure1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0BFg3.png)
[Azure2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gDkQb.png)

as well as Graph API roles:

`User.Read.All`
`GroupMember.Read.All`
`Application.Read.ALL`

I've also created the roles in the DB using the following query:

```
CREATE USER "sql-managed-identity" FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER;
ALTER ROLE db_datareader ADD MEMBER "sql-managed-identity";
ALTER ROLE db_datawriter ADD MEMBER "sql-managed-identity";
GO
```

Both SQL Management Studio and Powershell keep giving me the following error:

```
Cannot connect to different-vnet-sql.database.windows.net.
-

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
ManagedIdentityCredential authentication is unavailable. The requested identity has not been assigned to this resource.
Status: 400 (Bad Request)
Content:
{"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"Identity not found"}
Headers:
Content-Length: 68
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Date: Tue, 16 Jan 2024 14:56:05 GMT
Server: IMDS/150.870.65.1103
(Azure.Identity)
```

[SSMS Auth window image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IIT1I.png)

I've tried all the different auth methods in SSMS and attempted logging in using

- User-assigned managed identity name (as in Azure portal)
- User-assigned managed identity Client ID
- User-assigned managed identity Object (principal) ID

All give the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. The User Assigned Managed Identity is supposed to be setup on the SQL VM and not the SQL Server. From SSMS login using the Client ID of the MI, and not the MI name.

[Successful connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4eGRB.png)

Comment: What do you mean? Did you have to set the user managed identity under the identity section of the MI settings to get this to work?

Comment: @EJC sorry for being unclear. By MI, I mean Managed Identity, not Managed Instance for Azure SQL. So The problem was that I was using the identity for the SQL to log in to the SQL, where I was supposed to log into the SQL using the identity for the VM. This is the same regardless of user assigned or system assigned.